# How to find square and cubes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I want to find  the smallest positive integer A in which
$$10A$$ is a perfect square and $$6A$$ is a perfect cube

---

Thanks for the hint, I can see now I just needed $$2^5,3^2 , 5^3$$

Comment: Did you try to write $\;A^{10}\;$ ? If you did I think you *really* need to take a peek at  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: Do you mean smallest *positive* integer?

Comment: If you did mean to say $A^{10}$ and $A^6$, then every $A$ works... (as $A^{10}=(A^5)^2$ and $A^6 = (A^2)^3$).  Please clarify what exactly you mean by $A10$ and $A6$.

Comment: I wonder if he means the number formed by the concatenation of $10$ to the digits of A, which results in a perfect square, and likewise, the concatenation of 6 to the digits of A (resulting in a perfect cube.)

Comment: no matter the interpretation this question does not belong under [tag:number-theory]. // In the new version, I assume $10A$ means $A+ A + \ldots + A$ with 10 copies?

Comment: Indeed, 10*A. To what section does this belong? @WillieWong. Feel free to edit the tags

Comment: @JordanGlen No concatenation, just multiplication.

Comment: I see that now, after your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:  if you factor a square into prime factors, say $n^2=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots$ where the $p_i$ are primes, all the $a_i$ will be even.  Similarly for a cube, the $a_i$ will be multiples of $3$.  Here your primes are only $2,3,5$